# PHP, GoDaddy web site, Office 365 email - Can't send emails

Tags: php, email, smtp, office365

I have a web site on which I have a form for new members to fill out.  When done they hit submit the form is processed and should send an email to info@mywebsite.com.  The web site is on GoDaddy, the email is handled by Office 365.

I can not get the code correct to get the email sent.  The code below I'm sure contains more statements than are needed.  I've been trying everything I can think of hoping something would stick and so far nothing has.

Thanks, Alan

`

```
    <?php`

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 0);  // Don't show errors on browser

  function fErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
  {
    $message = "Error: [$errno] $errstr - $errfile:$errline";
    error_log($message . PHP_EOL, 3, "error_log.txt");
  }

  set_error_handler("fErrorHandler");

  $to = $subject = $message = $headers = '';
  $resultMsg = '';

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<b>New Membership Application</b><p>';
    $message .= 'First Name: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstName"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= ' Last Name: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["lastName"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= '   Address: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["address"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= '      City: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["city"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= '     State: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["state"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= '       Zip: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["zip"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= '     Phone: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= '     email: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= ' BirthDate: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["birthDate"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= 'Occupation: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["occupation"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= 'How Did You Hear: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["howDidUHear"]) . '</b><br>';
    $message .= 'Other Members: <b>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["otherMembers"]) . '</b>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    /* Instead of setting these values in php.ini. I set set them with ini.set */
    ini_set ('sendmail_from', 'MyWebSite' ); 
    ini_set ('SMTP', 'smtp.office365.com' );  
    ini_set ('smtp_server', 'smtp.office365.com' );  
    ini_set ('Host', 'smtp-mail.outlook.com');
    ini_set ('smtp_port', 587 );
    ini_set ('password', 'password' );
    ini_set ('auth_password', 'passowrd' );
    ini_set ('SMTPSecure', 'tls');
    ini_set ('IsSMTP', true);
    ini_set ('Username', 'info@MyWebSite.com');
    ini_set ('auth_username', 'info@MyWebSite.com');
    ini_set ('error_logfile', 'error.log');
    ini_set ('debug_logfile', 'debug.log');

    $headers = "From: MyWebSite\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";


    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "MyWebSite";
    $to = "info@MyWebSite.com";
    $subject = "New Membership Application";
  }
  
  if (mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers)) {
    $resultMsg = "Thank you! <br> Your application has been sent. <br> We will contact you shortly.";
  }

    ?>
```

`

I've tried everything I can think of.  It was working when I had similar code and the email server was on GoDaddy.  When I changed it to Office the emails never got sent.

As an aside, is there not an error message or some indication of what is not working that I could be checking?

Comment: GoDaddy is [notoriously strict](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow.com%3A+how+to+send+emails+from+php+via+godaddy&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS1092US1092&oq=stackover&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCAgAEEUYJxg7MggIABBFGCcYOzIGCAEQRRhAMgYIAhBFGDkyFAgDEAAYChhDGIMBGLEDGIAEGIoFMgcIBBAAGIAEMgkIBRAAGAoYgAQyCQgGEAAYChiABDIHCAcQABiABNIBCTI4MThqMGoxNagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) when it comes to email.

Comment: The SMTP related settings from `ini_set` or php.ini are for Windows only, per the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp-port

Comment: I don't recognise most of the INI directives you're setting. Where did you read about them? Builtin `mail()` function is notoriously unable to do any advanced stuff, such as encryption or authentication. The most straightforward way to send email is to use a reputable third-party library like Symfony Mailer or PHPMailer.